# Python tkinter entry() doesn't return any value to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox, tkinter-entry

I'm confused with how to get value entered in Entry() to a variable. any idea or suggestion on how to solve it.

---

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root=Tk()
root.title('Test')

e1=Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=1)

global e
e=e1.get()

def display():
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Message",message=e)

Submit=Button(root, justify=LEFT, padx=5,text="Submit",command= display).grid(row=2,sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

---

I want the value entered in entry box to be displayed in message box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` will reference a empty string and will not change because it is set only after the `Entry` widget initialization.

You need to call `e1.get()` to get current value of the entry widget.

```
def display():
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Message", message=e1.get())
```

Comment: ok.. but when i do like that, message box displaying some other value like "37582768get". The actual value that i entered is 5.

Comment: @Shiv18, This is what I've got: http://i.imgur.com/QQX7LXj.png . By the way, I removed `global e` statement.

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply.. yeh.. i removed e1. see this image.. http://i.imgur.com/Lub8YKA.jpg ... this is what i get.. @falsetru